# Can anyone quickly explain the following JS code

Tags: javascript

```
$('#menu1 > li > a.expanded + ul').slideToggle('medium');
```

I am trying to understand the

```
$('#menu1 > li > a.expanded + ul')
```

part. The context for this is I am creating a collapsable menu.

Comment: you no need to add your name.

Comment: That's called CSS. Google is your friend.

Comment: @Virus721 that's called *CSS selector*, used as an argument to (probably) jQuery which traverses the document to find HTML nodes that match given selector according to the rules defined by CSS selectors specification and some extensions provided by jQuery.

Comment: @pawel Yeah, so it's CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#menu1 > li > a.collapsed')
```

above statement means get the direct `li` child of menu parent and anchor with class name `collapsed` which is direct child of `li`

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu1">
    <li><a href="" class="collapsed">only this will get selected.</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="collapsed"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good answer, but I'd stress that it relies on jQuery library, otherwise `$` is undefined and the above JavaScript expression evaluates to "Error: $ is not a function" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

- `tag` searches for elements with a specific tag name
- `#id` searches for an element with a specific ID
- `.class` searches for elements with a specific class
- `a > b` searches for elements matching b that are children of elements matching a

**This means:**

`#menu > li > a.collapsed` searches for all `<a>`s with the class *collapsed* that are direct children of `<li>`s that are direct children of an element with the id *menu*.

Answer (score 0):

**#menu1 > li**  returns all "li" that are direct children of #menu1

**li > a.collapsed** -  This returns all hyperlinks  that have collapsed class that are direct children of "li"

So basicly **$('menu1 > li > a.collapsed')** returns all all hyperlinks  that have collapsed class that they are dilrect children of "li" elements that are direct children of #menu1

Answer (score 0):

You can find more about this in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) or [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
$('#menu1 > li > a.collapsed')
```

means to select all the "a" tags having the class "collapsed" which are the direct child elements of the "li" which are the direct child elements of the element with the id "menu1" .

Answer (score -1):

This is a JQuery selector for a parent child relationship.  [See docs here](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

It is basically saying:

1. Find id `menu1`
2. find a *direct* child `li`
3. find a *direct* child `a` with class `collapsed`

Comment: It *could* be because "child" usually means "any child" such as `#menu1 li a.collapsed` whereas `>` is **direct** children.

Comment: @h2ooooooo so what was wrong with my answer...why down vote for that..?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Updated. Could have been, but I think we had a drive-by down-voter pay us a visit. :)

Answer (score -1):

Get all the anchors (a) with the collapsed class from the listitems (li) within the element with id menu1.
Also see: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/